# Change the default date format while exporting the resultset data using OpenCSV

Tags: database, date, load, opencsv, universe

I am trying to export the data into CSV using OpenCSV.

The Database is Universe Db and the CSV generates fine with "$" as the separator.

However, when we tried to load the same CSV data into an IBM DB2 database it is failing because of an incompatible date format(i.e `DD-MMM-YYYY`) as IBM DB2 doesn't support this format.

Code to generate the CSV:

```
private CSVWriter writer; 
writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(savePath + "\\" + tableName+ ".csv"),"UTF-8"), '$',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER); 
writer.writeAll(rs, false); //rs is the resultset returned for the select query 
writer.flush();
```

We are loading the csv using DB2s load & imp command.

How do I change the default date format while generating the CSV?

Purpose of the activity : 
To load the data from a Universe db to an IBM DB2 database.

Note : Universe DB doesn't support updating the resultset, hence that option was not taken into consideration :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a custom ResultSetHelperService :

```
String filemane = "export.csv";
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
ResultSetHelperService resultService = new ResultSetHelperService();
resultService.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
resultService.setDateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
csvWriter.setResultService(resultService);
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently in the trunk build of openCSV there are changes to the ResultSetHelperService to allow you to set the date and datetime formats to the format you desire and then you can call the setResultSetHelper in the CSVWriter you create before processing the result set.

These will be out in the 3.6 build which is slated to come out in the next couple of weeks (I am just waiting for the main contributor for this release to come back from honeymoon ).

Comment: That must be a cool feature which i am also waiting for long.. :) :)
how would i come to know the release of OpenCSV 3.6 version?

Comment: Either on the sourceforge page - https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/ or you can check the maven central repo - http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.opencsv%22%20AND%20a%3A%22opencsv%22   I post to both on the same day.   I also try to keep the wiki up to date so you can check there.  https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/wiki/What%27s%20new/   or https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/news/

Comment: It will be a great help if  you share some example the usage of ResultSetHelperService  and setResultSetHelper  in context of handling the date while writing into csv.

Comment: I thought I had a good test showing both the ResultSetHelperService and the CSVWriter but I only had individual tests.  I will try and get a good integration test or update the FAQs later on but for now if you have used result sets before with opencsv then it won't be that much different.   
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(somewriter);
    ResultSetHelperService service = new ResultSetHelperService();
    service.setDateFormat("YYYYMMDD");
    service.setDateTimeFormat("YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
    writer.setResultService(service);

3.6 was just released today!